# Repository delegating to an external object storage

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a REST endpoint to store Products.
Every product has a name, a price and an image (e.g. PNG file) so I send to my REST endpoint the product info (product name and price) and an image file.
Images are stored in an external object storage (e.g. Amazon S3) so I store the image and get a URL that I add to my product entity before save it to my DB.

My question: is the repository responsible for those 2 tasks (storing in an external object storage, saving products to DB) ?
So I will have somthing like:

```
productRepository.save(productInfo, productImageInputstream) {

 String URL = externalObjectStorage.store(productImageInputstream);
 Product product = new Product(productInfo, URL)
 return productRepository.save(product);

}
```

Is it a good design ?

Thanks

Comment: I might consider durability requirements in this case first.  For example: Is it okay if the externalObjectStore is unavailable and causes the save to fail.  If the external storage succeeds but the database fails, are orphaned external objects okay?  Depending on system size and scalability requirements, a queuing system may be helpful + it would allow you to completely decouple the two storage repos.

Answer (score 0):

If images are important to your business, then it is inevitable to separate the concerns. Nevertheless, I still strongly suggest to decouple the two concerns and think more about the actual interface between them.

With the two concerns decoupled you can:

- easily replace S3 URLs with CDN URLs at some point in the future
- compress and scale images to different output sizes, should you ever require that
- reuse the photo upload logic in other parts of the application

If you need to make sure that every product has a photo, create a business service for that, which then uses your CRUD repositories to store the data / photo to their respective backend solution:

```
interface ProductService {
    Product createProductWithImage(productData, imageData);
}
```